# Firebase auth not persisting on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

For some reason when I refresh the page the authentication doesn't persist and itll redirect the user back to sign in, I've seen a couple other postings about this on here but still doesn't work in my case. I'm using nextjs and I have localhost added to my signin method on firebase, it won't let me add localhost:3000. I don't want the user to be redirected to the sign in I want it to be persisted, so however many times the user refreshes the page it stays the same. I'm using nextjs, Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        const userDetails = fetchDetails(user.uid);
        userDetails.then((use) => setUser(use.data()));
      } else {
        router.push("/signin");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I've also tried it just like this too:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        const userDetails = fetchDetails(user.uid);
        userDetails.then((use) => setUser(use.data()));
      } else {
        router.push("/signin");
      }
    });
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. Were you able to resolve this issue?